# pandas indexing error with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe that I am trying to create a tsplot with seaborn and I am getting index duplicate errors.  My question is two fold.  First off, when I look at the data there are no duplicate indexes (sample df is given below):

```
          BOLD campaign  time      type
0     2.735430  6041148     3   Default
1     1.356943  6041148     3      None
2          NaN  6041148     3  Vertical
3     9.550452  6013866     6   Default
4     1.000000  6013866     6      None
5          NaN  6013866     6  Vertical
6   322.675089  6086810     8   Default
7     1.508849  6086810     8      None
8   773.393385  6086810     8  Vertical
9    43.396084  6046619    10   Default
10   26.124405  6046619    10      None
11         NaN  6046619    10  Vertical
12  103.955111  6065909    10   Default
13    1.000000  6065909    10      None
14         NaN  6065909    10  Vertical
15    9.744664  6013866     9   Default
16    9.031970  6013866     9      None
17         NaN  6013866     9  Vertical
18   10.980322  6065742     8   Default
19    0.803821  6065742     8      None
```

However when I go to plot this dataframe with

```
sns.tsplot(df, time="time", unit="campaign", condition="type", value="BOLD")
```

I get

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Can someone explain why this is?  I do not see any duplicate entries (or indices).  I also tried using drop_duplicates and get the same result

Comment: Your unit variable and time variable are effectively identical, I don't think you'll be able to make this plot using tsplot.